# Perl command line: single vs. double quotes for directory arguments

Tags: windows, command-line, quotes

I'm having trouble understanding command argument quotations for perl in Windows. Using the following program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;

my $dir = shift;

die 'Usage: perl Folderize.pl <directory>' unless $dir;

die "$dir doesn't exist" unless -d $dir;
```

I get different results depending on if I use single or double quotes for a directory. If I call it with `'perl script.pl 'H:\Test!'` it prints "'H:\Test!' doesn't exist". However, if I call it with `'perl script.pl "H:\Test!"`, it works just fine. Why is this happening?

Comment: What happens if you dbl-quote your use of $dir in the perl code? Good Luck.

Comment: `-d "$dir"` still fails if single quotes were used on the command line. Using no quotes works too, in this case, but only because the path has no spaces.

Comment: Are you sure it says `H:\Test!` doesn't exist? And not `H:\Test`?

Comment: @Quentin Yes the exclamation was there. Does that surprise you?

Comment: Yes. The quotes should only be able to make a difference in your interpreter, so if it was doing something with special characters then the difference should be visible from the Perl error message.

Comment: In the future, you'll get many more eyes on your perl questions if you include a tag for perl. Yes, it wasn't really a perl problem, but something anyone that does perl on windows will have dealt with. Glad you got a good solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the command-line, quoting rules are the purview of the shell, not the program (perl). The rules for Unix shells are similar to the rules for Perl (double quote interpolates variables, single quotes don't) but the Windows "shell" has different rules. Some main differences are:

- Single quote `'` is not a special character

  `C:>\ dir > 'foo'`

will create a file called `'foo'` (the quotes will be included in the filename)

- `""` double quotes interpolate environment variables that look like `%NAME%`, but it won't try to interpret perl scalar variable names as environment variables:

  `C:>\ perl -e "print '%PATH'"`
- The Windows shell will "close" your quote for you if you forget

  `C:>\ perl -e "print qq/Hello world/`

  `Hello world`

This works even though I forgot to use the second double quote.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the Perl interpreter. It is the shell that interprets commands and their arguments.

When you supply a double-quoted argument, for example `"H:\Test!"`, the shell treats everything inside the quotes as the contents of the string, and what is passed to the Perl interpreter is the string without the quotes.

By contrast, when you supply `'H:\Test!'`, the shell takes the single quotes as a part of the string itself, and passes it this way to the Perl interpreter.

Comment: With that file name, it probably isn't bash, and bash doesn't pass the single quotes as part of the string.

Comment: I removed the shebang line. I have there out of habit, but I don't need it because I work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the drive letter I assume you work under (the thumb of) Windows. Then you'll have just to accept, that double quotes are the one and only quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using Getopt::Long instead of doing your own argument parsing

http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html

```
    use Getopt::Long;


    GetOptions
    (
        'dir=s' => \$dir,
    ) or die ("Couldnot process arguments");
```

in this case dir will have directory whether the user does

```
    yourscript.pl -dir = foo
    yourscript.pl -dir  "foo"
    yourscript.pl -dir  foo
```

If you do this

```
    GetOptions
    (
        'dir=@s' => \@dir,
    ) or die ("Couldnot process arguments");
```

You will get all the directories in a plain old array

```
yourscript.pl -dir  foo -dir blah
```

Comment: OP isn't doing any parsing of switches, so Getopt::Long here does nothing.

Comment: Pretty cool. I think I'll use this somewhere, though not in this script because I'm only parsing the one argument.